# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to print from my mutable list but keep getting out of bounds. I added the members to the menu at the bottom, then every time I try to print something from a member of a list, I get an error. These members are objects of the class being stored as a list. I am thinking it has to do with the way I wrote the list but I can't figure it out.

I tried adding the members to the list in different ways but it results in the same error.

```
class membership ()
      {
        var number: Int? = null
        var name: String? = null
        var address: String? = null
        var zip: String? = null
        var phone: String? = null
        var memberSince: String? = null
        var memberType: Char? = null

    }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

var Members: MutableList<membership> = mutableListOf()

    var member1 = membership()
    member1.number = 1
    member1.name = "George Jetson"
    member1.address ="123 Main St."
    member1.zip = "99207"
    member1.memberSince = "12/01/1997"
    member1.memberType = 'L'

Members[0] = member1

    println(Members[0].name)
}

// I have more members.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck (ArrayList.java:653) 
 at java.util.ArrayList.set (ArrayList.java:444) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:45)
```

Comment: you should try to respect the naming convention (class Membership, var members)

Answer (score 3):

I would say you can not assign item 0, if it has not been set before. The member1 needs to be added with

```
Members.add(member1)
```

Comment: Hey I tried this out and it gave me this error "Assignment operators ambiguity"

Comment: Christian is right that you cannot assign to item 0 if it has not been set before, but you should not write `+=`. Instead, `Members.add(member1)` should work.

Comment: `+=` would work well if `Members` was a `val`.  (It doesn't work if it's a `var`, because it could mean either `Members = Members + something` or `Members.add(something)`, and the compiler can't tell which you mean.)  BTW, this question would be easier to follow if it kept to the usual coding convention and named it `members`.

Comment: you are right, sorry, I corrected the answer accordingly.